# Does Mac keeps a history of all actions I have done with files/folders similar to terminal?

Tags: macos, backup, data-recovery

2 days ago I accidentally deleted my work folder which include many projects aI have worked on them for last 2 weeks and I didn't packed them up at all.

I used [Dr.Cleaner](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dr.cleaner-clean-disk-optimize/id921458519?mt=12) to clean up "un-wanted" files, but it seems (i don't remember exactly) I deleted many files permanently and my work folder is one of them.

After that I used my computer for many operations (read/delete/add/copy and past files and folders), for about 12 hours until, I discovered the sad news.

Unfortunately I didn't use Time Machine, I didn't backup manually at all, and I didn't have any software installed prior deletion to help me to recover what I have lost.

I stopped doing any internal operations (mentioned above) to avoid overwrite the physical part on my hard drive (hoping to recover that area using 3rd part software).

Right now I'm using "Wondershare Data Recover", "Stellar Phoenix Mac Data Recovery" and "Disk Drill" to recover what I have lost, but nothing promising yet.

I don't know if I just gave up and accept the fact my work file is gone. Or there are other way to help recover these files or at least understand it's history??!!

My question is, Does Mac keeps history of all action user does for every file/folder? Similar to Terminal (bash/zsh)?

Also, I'm looking for Dr.Cleaner log file (if there's any) that keeps history of it's all action and operation. I can't find it at all. Does it have one?

Last thing, after all of that, do I still have a chance to recover my lost folder??

Thanks!

Comment: Operation was successful however the patient is dead :(  no way 12 hours later.

Answer (score 1):

To your first question:

Yes it does keep record of lots of stuff--lots of records.

Open the Console log and have fun looking through it.

To your other questions:

Only if you realize the mistake immediately some stuff is recoverable.

It also depends how full your disk is (theoretically), so the deleted information would not be immediately overwritten.